# Color to fill polygon is not showing in flutter_map

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

I'm using the `flutter_map` library and for some reason I can't fill-in polygons with any color. The code I have is the following and can't find any problem with the implementation.

```dart
if (polygonList.isNotEmpty)
  PolygonLayer(
    polygons: [
      for (var area in polygonList)
        if (area['polygon'] != null)
          Polygon(
            points: area['polygon'],
            borderColor: getColor(area['color']),
            // For some reason this following color is not being displayed.
            color:
                getColor(area['color']).withOpacity(0.5),
            borderStrokeWidth: 2,
          ),
    ],
  )
```

I already tried to hardcode some regular color, but it doesn't work either. It is weird because the color does appear in the border. My Flutter environment (result of `flutter --version`) is the following:

- Flutter 3.7.12 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
- Framework • revision 4d9e56e694 (8 days ago) • 2023-04-17 21:47:46 -0400
- Engine • revision 1a65d409c7
- Tools • Dart 2.19.6 • DevTools 2.20.1

Also, the version of flutter_map I have in my project is `flutter_map: ^3.1.0`.

Hope you can help!